# how to combine multiple rows into one row with different column values using ssis composant

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am working on my ETL and I have to combine multiple rows with same id in one row with different informations in different columns .
Here it is an example of what i got and what i want using ssis transformation.

```
Mat(PK)       Activity     EntryDate      Grade  
--------------------------------------------------
12             Null        01/01/2000      Null  
12             Dev          NULL          NULL   
12             NULL         NULL          Eng+8   

Mat(PK)       Activity     EntryDate      Grade  
---------------------------------------------------
12              Dev       01/01/2000      Eng+8
```

I made an sql request to do that but when I add this request in my OLE DB DESTINATION it returns that this composant doesn't accept group by .
Here it's my sql request:

```
INSERT INTO [TestPFEDW].[dbo].[tsst]

SELECT DISTINCT
 [Matricule ]

,MAX([Prénom/Nom ])   AS [Nom_Complet]

  ,MAX([Consultant ?])AS [Consultant]
  ,MAX([Etat])          AS [Etat]
  ,MAX([Date Dém#])   AS [Date_Démmarage]
  ,MAX([Date Préavis])   AS [Date_Préavis]
  ,MAX([TN _Mission LD])   AS [TN _Mission LD]
  ,MAX([Manage])   AS [Manager]
  ,MAX([Observation])    AS [Observation]
  ,MAX([Entry Date]) AS [Date_Entrer]
  ,MAX([Date d'embauche])  AS [Date_Embauche]
  ,MAX([Ing/Tech])  AS [Ing/Tech]
  ,MAX([Expérience TOTALE as is_Rouge à corriger sur Sage]) AS [Expérience_Totale]
  ,MAX([Grade FI]) AS [Grade]
  ,MAX([Fonction_ATC])  AS [Fonction_ATC]
  ,MAX([Ancienneté Telnet_Au 1er Nov 2017]) AS [Ancienneté] 
  ,MAX([Spécialité])  AS [Spécialité]
  ,MAX([Natonalité])  AS [Natonalité]
  ,MAX([Date de sortie]) AS [Date_Sortie]
  ,MAX([Experience anterieur (mois)])AS [Experience_anterieur (mois)]
  ,MAX([Prestataire]) AS [Prestataire]
  ,MAX([Affiliation])  AS [Affiliation]
  ,MAX([Activité])  AS [Activité]

  FROM [TestPFEODS].[dbo].[Consultant]  AS A
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [TestPFEDW].[dbo].[tsst] AS B WHERE B.[Matricule ] = A.[Matricule ]) and [Matricule ] like '%ATS%'  group by [Matricule ]
```

Comment: Use an Execute SQL Task instead of a data flow task run the INSERT...SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put INSERT INTO statements in OLDEDB Destination.
In your case, Either use SQL task or in DFT add OLEDB source and OLEDB destination.
In Source add your select statement and in Destination select your table and map columns accordingly